# Load image with Glide for AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-appwidget-list

I'm working on my first app widget.
Everthing is fine except one thing. I can't find out, how can I load image into ImageView at RemoteViewsFactroy's getViewAt() method with Glide. I allways get error, because I've to run into(AppWidgetTarget) at MainThread, but I can't call new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) from RemoteViewsFactory.

Comment: you can achieve this using universal image loader. Do you want to load image only using glide?

Answer (score 2):

Glide has support for this by providing the [AppWidgetTarget](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/AppWidgetTarget.html) class.

While updating your widget in `onUpdate()`, you create a new AppWidgetTarget, pass it the `RemoteViews` object, the id of your image view, and the appwidgetId and then invoke glide in nearly the same way as you would for an imageview in your app.

```
    appWidgetTarget = new AppWidgetTarget( context, rv, R.id.custom_view_image, appWidgetIds );

    Glide
            .with( context.getApplicationContext() ) // safer!
            .load( GlideExampleActivity.eatFoodyImages[3] )
            .asBitmap()
            .into( appWidgetTarget );
```

Example code above taken from this [wonderful set of glide tutorials](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets).  The tutorials cover many practical aspects of using glide.

Similarly, a [NotificationTarget](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/NotificationTarget.html) target class is also provided by glide - it solves the same problem, but for notifications instead of appWidgets.